# Cursor disappearing, in playmode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a button for pausing (android game), and I've made a script for it, but when I play the game, the mouse cursor disappears and and don't know how to click the button for pausing, I even ran my game in android but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {
bool isPaused;
void Start ()
{
    isPaused = false;
    //Cursor.visible = true; // i also done this but nothing happens
    //Screen.lockCursor = false;
}
void OnGUI ()
{ 
    if (!isPaused)
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-100,Screen.height/2+1,180,40),"Pause"))
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            isPaused = true;
        }
    }
    if (isPaused)
    {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 + 80, 180, 40), "Play"))
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
            isPaused = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because is not setted on playmode I suppose.
Try to use:

```
Cursor.visible = true;
```

On a script attached to a object on scene.

Comment: But by the way, why do you need a cursor on a touchscreen device?

The finger is the mouse click. All the buttons on de Editor works with mouse click, but when you export to Android all buttons work with finger tap automatically

Comment: I don't know which version of Unity you are using, but if it's 5 or above, GUI class is deprecated. Try to use UI classes, inside namespace UnityEngine.UI